# Block evaluation of template tags but not variables

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django's template engine to evaluate user-supplied template strings.  I would like to allow the users to use the variable mapping functionality, but not the tags or filters.

For example:

```
from django.template import Context, Template

user_template_string = "V1: {{ var1 }}.  V2: {{ var2|truncatechars:5 }}.  {% if var3 %} yes {% else %} no {% endif %}"
template = Template(user_template_string)

context = {'var1': 'One',
           'var2': '123456789',
           'var3': True}

output = template.render(context=Context(context))
# Desired output:
# "V1: One.  V2: 123456789.  {% if var3 %} yes {% else %} no {% endif %}"
```

Is there a way to configure the template engine to render variables but ignore tags and filters?  Or is my best bet to sanitize the user input and try to strip out all tags and filters that they may include?

Comment: Why it is needed to not evaluate the tags and filters? the purpose may help to find a solution.

Comment: @AhmedNourEldeen I am trying to limit the access that users have because the tool I'm building is in its early stages and I just want to keep the product surface small (for both simplicity and security's sakes)